# Is there a script to monitor new processes started on WIndows 10?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a command prompt open for a split second occasionally (once an hour maybe?) just enough to minimize my windows but not long enough for me to see what it said.

Is there a powershell or command prompt script I can run that will continuously run until i close it that captures new processes that started? Or maybe commands that are run?

There is nothing in event viewer, ran 50 anti-malware / AV solutions (it might be one of them getting updates?).

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=windows%2010%20window%20split%20second#hl=en&tbs=qdr:m&q=windows+10+popup+split+second